# socket webserver returns html but vue axios get does't work

Tags: python, vue.js

I write a simple web server returns html page which contains vue axios get funcion,but the get function does't work.
[image]
But when I check the page with browser it works and returns datas.
[image]

I put it in github
[socket webserver&vue][3]

socket server:

```
def server_start():
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind(('', 8000))
    s.listen(128)

    while True:
        client, addr = s.accept()
        r = client.recv(1024)
        # print(r.decode('utf-8'))
        path = (r.decode('utf-8')).split(' ')[1]
        print(path)
        t = threading.Thread(target=request_handle, args=(path, client))
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()

def request_handle(path, client):
    url.response_data(path, client)

if name == 'main': 
    server_start()
```

url codes:

```
import os
import view

url = [
    ('/test', view.test),
    ('/test1', view.test1),
    ('/index', view.index),

]


def response_data(path, client):
    if path == '/' or path == '':
        path = '/index'
    if not os.path.exists('statics' + path + '.html'):
        with open('statics/404.html', 'rb') as f:
            data = f.read()
        rline = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
        rheader = 'Server: PWS/1.0\r\n'
        response_data = (rline + rheader + '\r\n').encode('utf-8') + data
        client.send(response_data)

else:
    for k in url:
        if path == k[0]:
            return k[1](path, client)
```

view codes:

```
def open_response_data(path, client):
with open('statics' + path + '.html', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

rline = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
rheader = 'Server: PWS/1.0\r\n'
response_data = (rline + rheader + '\r\n').encode('utf-8') + data
client.send(response_data)


def test(path, client):
    open_response_data(path, client)

def test1(path, client):
    open_response_data(path, client)

def index(path, client):
    open_response_data(path, client)
```

some others:
The function request_handle in test_socket220415.py calls url.response_data,
and the view return html pages.

Comment: Please do not post your github source, paste code right here.

Comment: Learning django and trying to write a socket websever but some problems above,I paste codes here.But why not put github source here?I thinks it is easy to read.